# C++ проверка типа данных в шаблоне: ссылка, указатель или объект?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

Я могу узнать, к какому типу данных принадлежит параметр шаблона:

```
template<class... _Ty_node>
Value_polihedral(_Ty_node&&... _nodes) {
    if constexpr((_STD is_same<_Ty_node, decltype(_V_nodes)::value_type&>::value && ...)) {
        (_V_nodes.emplace_back(_STD forward<_Ty_node>(_nodes)), ...);
    } else if constexpr(((_STD is_same<_Ty_node, Point&>::value || 
                            _STD is_same<_Ty_node, Point3d&>::value) && ...)) {
      (_V_nodes.emplace_back(_STD make_shared<Value::Point>(_nodes)), ...);
    } else {
        static_assert(false, "The function expected a type that matches nodes type. ");
    }
    _V_nodes_transform.reserve(4);
}
```

Но как быть, если я не знаю, какой тип может быть на входе и всё, что мне нужно это правильно обработать элементы.
Если параметр - указатель, то нужно обращаться через (->), а если ссылка, то через точку(.)

Нужно что-то вроде такого

```
template<class... _Ty_node>
Value_polihedral(_Ty_node&&... _nodes) {
    if constexpr((is_ptr<_Ty_node> && ...)) {
        (sum += _nodes->weight, ...);  // ->
    } else{
        (sum += _nodes.weight, ...);  // .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Начиная с С++11, в стандартной библиотеке (в файле `type_traits`) появился шаблон класса `is_pointer`

```
template< class T >
struct is_pointer;
```

Он позволяет проверить, является ли `T` указателем на обьект или функцию (но не указателем на член класса). Чтобы узнать результат, необходимо обратиться к статическому члену `value`, который равен `true`, если `T` является указателем и `false` в противном случае.
Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_pointer<int>::value << std::endl;    // 0
    std::cout << std::is_pointer<int*>::value << std::endl;   // 1

    return 0;
}
```

В С++17 появился вспомогательный шаблон переменной

```
template< class T >
constexpr bool is_pointer_v = is_pointer<T>::value;
```

который позволяет избежать обращения к члену `value`.
Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_pointer_v<int> << std::endl;    // 0
    std::cout << std::is_pointer_v<int*> << std::endl;   // 1

    return 0;
}
```

Более подробно здесь: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer